# order a php array by a sub string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, timestamp

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20140929102023_taxonomies.zip
    [1] => 20140915175317_taxonomies.zip
    [2] => 20140804112307_taxonomies.zip
    [3] => 20141002162349_taxonomies.zip
)
```

I'd like order this array by first 14 characters of strings, that represents a date.
I'd like an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20140804112307_taxonomies.zip
    [1] => 20140915175317_taxonomies.zip
    [2] => 20140929102023_taxonomies.zip
    [3] => 20141002162349_taxonomies.zip
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function with the natural sorting algorithm should give you the result you are looking for.  It's as simple as this.

```
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

This will updat the existing `$array` variable, you do not need to store the return of the `sort` function.  It simply returns true or falseon success and failure.

The sort function will update the keys as well, if for some reason you need to maintain the keys, and just update the order, you can use [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

```
asort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

PHP has tons of ways to sort arrays, you can find the manual for that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use natural sorting algorithms. A normal [sort()](http://php.net/sort) would produce the effect you desire, as it will compare each string "starting from the left". For example "20141002162349_taxonomies.zip" is bigger than "20140929102023_taxonomies" because the fifth character (the first digit of the month) is 1 in the first and 0 in the second (and 1 > 0, even in a string - comparison works with ASCII code points).

So:

```
<?php
$array = array('20141002162349_taxonomies.zip', '20140929102023_taxonomies.zip', '20140804112307_taxonomies.zip', '20140915175317_taxonomies.zip');
sort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "20140804112307_taxonomies.zip"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "20140915175317_taxonomies.zip"
  [2]=>
  string(29) "20140929102023_taxonomies.zip"
  [3]=>
  string(29) "20141002162349_taxonomies.zip"
}
```